# x axis tick label won't fit using ggplot2 in Rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I'm trying to make a graph using a log scale with ggplot2 in Rstudio and the last x axis tick label won't fit on the graph.

Here is my plotting code

```
ggplot(data=user.counts, aes(x=counter, y=Number_obs)) +
geom_line()+
scale_y_log10(breaks=c(1,10,100,1000,10000),labels=c(1,10,100,1000,10000))+
scale_x_log10(breaks=c(1,10,100,1000,10000),labels=c(1,10,100,1000,10000))+
labs(x="No. observers",y="No. observations",title="")+
theme_bw(base_size = 20)
```

and this is a screenshot of my graph:

[image: graph]

I've tried making the plot pane larger in RStudio and popping out the plot pane and both methods didn't make a difference.

Many thanks

Comment: Is there any data in the viewable range (no. of observations)  between 1000 and 10000 observers?

Comment: Try a smaller `base_size` in `theme_bw()`.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**. Right-align x-axis labels:

```
ggplot(data=user.counts, aes(x=counter, y=Number_obs)) +
  geom_line()+
  scale_y_log10(breaks=c(1,10,100,1000,10000), labels=c(1,10,100,1000,10000))+
  scale_x_log10(breaks=c(1,10,100,1000,10000), labels=c(1,10,100,1000,10000))+
  labs(x="No. observers",y="No. observations",title="")+
  theme_bw(base_size = 20) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1)) # default is hjust = 0.5
```

[image: plot1]

**Option 2**. Increase expansion constant:

```
ggplot(data=user.counts, aes(x=counter, y=Number_obs)) +
  geom_line()+
  scale_y_log10(breaks=c(1,10,100,1000,10000), labels=c(1,10,100,1000,10000))+
  scale_x_log10(breaks=c(1,10,100,1000,10000), labels=c(1,10,100,1000,10000),
                expand = c(0.1, 0))+ # default is c(0.05, 0) for continuous variable
  labs(x="No. observers", y="No. observations", title="")+
  theme_bw(base_size = 20)
```

[image: plot2]

Sample data used:

```
set.seed(1)
user.counts <- data.frame(
  counter = seq(1, 1000),
  Number_obs = seq(1000, 1) * 10 + rnorm(1000)
)
```